# How to find whether any file of a directory contains a specific string using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I need to check if the string `M1039C28` is inside any file of the directory `/var/opt`.
It should echo `true` if the string is found or echo `String not found` if the string is not found.

Sample:

```
cd /var/opt/;
if [ find ./ -type f -exec grep -Hni "M1039C28" {} ';']
then
    echo "String found"
else
    INFO "String not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider using `grep` with options `-q` (suppress any output) and `-r` (recursive search in a directory):

```
grep -qr "search-query" /path/to/dir && echo "FOUND" || echo "NOT FOUND"
```

`grep` will exit with code `1` if it could not find the string in any files.
For more information, see the [man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#EXIT_STATUS)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you base your script on this command:

```
grep -l "M1039C28" * | wc -l
```

If the result is 0, then the entry is not found.
If the result is 1 or more, the entry is found.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large directory and want to search recursively, try using [the silver searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) if not already installed, you can with on Debian `sudo apt install silversearcher-ag` or `brew install the_silver_searcher` on MacOS. Use it like this.

```
ag "M1039C28" path/to/search && echo "FOUND" || echo "NOT FOUND"
```

note path argument is optional, by default it searches current path recursively.